# Modify Player Settings from C# - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have been developing a Cardboard VR game using the Unity game engine.

I  have a lobby where the player can choose a room to play the game in, set their handle etc... I would like this lobby to be a 2D canvas, then transition to vr when a room is chosen.

An excellent example of what I mean is showcased in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dtamobile.vrxracer&hl=en_US).

My question is: is there a way to modify the Player Settings in Unity; more specifically Player Settings > Player > XR Settings, then toggle "Virtual Reality Supported" on and off from a C# script?

If not, do you have any other recommendations on how to solve my problem?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings.html ?

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Menyus! You just set `XRSettings.enabled = false;`

Comment: Test if it works in release tho

Comment: I built the game and ran it as an apk on a compatible android device and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with your game ;)